# How to create multiple maps under the same array

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this as my output in firebase:

```
myArray
  0
     array0.item1: "data1"
  1
     array0.item2: "data2"
```

But I wanted my output to be like this:

```
myArray
  0
     array0.item1: "data1"
     array0.item2: "data2"
```

Here's is my declaration:

```
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> map1 = {'array0.item1' : "data1"};
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> map2 = {'array0.item2' : "data2"};
```

Here's my code:

```
        await db.collection(Paths.myPath).doc(uid).set({
          'myArray' : FieldValue.arrayUnion([map1,map2]),
        }, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

I try to search an example of this but normally it require a new class to be created but if possible, I wanted it to be created without using a new class. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a map in order to do this.